java field usage in same assignment as shadowed name
why is:
class A {
  int a;
  void foo() {
    int a = a;
  }
}

not allowed, but
class A {
  int a;
  void foo() {
    int b = a;
    int a = b;
  }
}

is? Can't java recognize that the RHS for the identifier executes in a different environment than after the assignment takes place?
If no, is this covered anywhere in the docs or semantic rules? For example, C++ allows this.

You can use int a = this.a;.

The Java Language Specification says this about the scope of a local variable (emphasis mine):

The scope of a local variable declared in a block by a local variable declaration statement (§14.4.2) is the rest of the block, starting with the declaration's own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in the local variable declaration statement.

This means that the local variable a is already in scope after the = sign. As a result, the field a is shadowed.
One reason for designing the scope of a local variable like this is to give an arguably more useful error message when you try to use a local variable in its own declaration. The error message would be something like "x has not been initialised", instead of something like "cannot find x in scope".
Of course, it is possible to allow this kind of assignment and also give useful error messages, but that adds complexity.

I'm currently writing a compiler for a subset of Java, and I think this way adds more complexity, because it requires you to think about initialization-before-use. If it executed in the prior environment, this would be wholly simple. As for the quote, "further declarators to the right in the local variable statement" seems to imply something like a = 1, b = a, but not of the RHS of the equal. Am I interpreting that correctly?

@user129393192 Yes, that is what "further declarators" means. But the RHS of the equal is mentioned too. That's the bolded part "the declaration's own initializer".

Your error message reasoning is interesting. I would say that for a novice user, this error message could be arguably more useful; however, I found myself confused, because it did not fit my intuitive notion of how type environments are updated.

@user129393192 A valid point. Language design is all about this kind of trade-offs. "It requires you to think about initialization-before-use" Should you not think about that? I wouldn't like a language that doesn't require you to think about that :-)

@user129393192 it sounds like you are asking the question: "Why was it designed this way?" which is not appropriate for SO. You should email Gosling and pray his memory of stuff decided 30 years ago is sound. Alternatively if you are asking: "Wouldn't it be better if java adopted this change" - java strongly dislikes changing stuff like this, so, it's a pointless argument. The most SO-acceptable form is: "Can someone muse as to why the way things work is useful in contrast to some other way", but, be aware that often the answer is 'just cuz' - some vague choice made 30 years ago.

@rzwitserloot While OP might also be wondering that, the question as it is currently written does not ask "why was it designed this way?". It asks "is this covered anywhere in the docs or semantic rules?", which I think is an on-topic question for SO.

@Sweeper this excellent answer covers that particular take on the question, however, the first comment on this question is OP following up on 'why'. I'm responding to that 'why'.

Since this is an excellent answer, I plan to accept it. I am curious of language design though, which is the reason for the follow-up comment. Thoughts from other people are always good, educational, and interesting to hear @rzwitserloot

As for your initialization-before-use comment @Sweeper , you are correct. However, for the simple compiler I am building, it would require me to think about code analysis as opposed to simple type checking. For this reason, my small subset of Java may not even be called Java, since it will simply initialize locals to 0 on declaration.
